# Expectation of $\int_0^t f(s) d X_s$ for $(X_t)$ $L^1$ semimartingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ be a semimartingale such that $E[|X_t|] < \infty$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a real function such that $g(t)=\int_0^t f(s) d X_s$ is finite for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Under which necessary and sufficient conditions does $E[g(t)]= \int_0^t f(s) d E[X_s]$ ? I am tempted by saying that this equality holds always. But what if $E[X_s]$ is not of bounded variation?

Related question I asked a few days ago: [Is the mean of an integrable semimartingale of bounded variation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590104/is-the-mean-of-an-integrable-semimartingale-of-bounded-variation)

Comment: My 2 cents maybe you should decompose your semimartingale into a local martingale and a FV process (not unique), then examine under announcing sequence (and maybe also add some conditions to get dominated convergence?) to get some results, also it is not clear in your post if the function "f" is stochastic or not. (also a L¨2 hypotthesis might help as there are more nice properties for L^2 processes).

Comment: @TheBridge $f$ is just a real function, not a stochastic process.